# Can kernel functions have different virtual addresses

Tags: c, windows, linux, compiler-construction, kernel

This is more like a knowledge question than actual implementation. I was wondering if any kernel function can have different virtual addresses after the system starts. My understanding  of compilation for executable is virtual addresses are assigned for its binary but virtual to physical is done at run time by os.(paging. I know that stuff. So, no need 2 explain)
But in case of kernel functions, I see them having different virtual addresses when every time I restart the system. 
1. How are kernel functions mapped in the address range? 2. Can they be mapped to different virtual addresses at run time. (I wonder how it is possible) 3. How is the address mapping for dlls? Are they given a virtual address at compilation or assigned a relative address at run time? (I think that's how it is done.) 4. Is there any way to find if any kernel virtual address is pinned to physical memory.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traditionally, executables are assigned a fixed virtual address mapping at compile time. However, in recent years, it has become evident that this is bad for security - attackers can use their knowledge of exactly where things are in memory as part of an exploit. To help mitigate this, one can use position-independent or relocatable executables to allow the load address to be randomized (at least on Linux). However, this comes with a downside - starting the program takes more time, as the dynamic loader must perform relocations (either that, or there is additional overhead at runtime from position-independent machine code).

For the OS kernel, the additional overhead is trivial compared to the rest of the time spent booting; indeed, the Windows kernel actually dynamically links many of its components. So the kernel is an obvious place to randomize the load address.

Comment: Thanks.Can kernel unload and reload the module at different location at run time.It tries to do relative mapping of kernel libraries but once loaded will the virtual address change?(I guess NO as other modules are dependent on those addresses.But if those addresses are maintained in a table which needs to be queried then runtime load/unload can work.So,kernel can keep virtual addresses moving at run time.However system may not able to do it for some critical kernel routines which cant be unloaded at runtime) Do u know if we can find out if any virtual address is pinned to phy memory?

Comment: @agent.smith, please open a different question rather than asking complex followups in a comment. Also, you seem to have multiple questions to ask; please make sure to ask these as _separate questions_, since some people may only know the answer to some of the questions but not all of them

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How are kernel functions mapped in the address range?

They aren't necessarily mapped into user space at all. Up until I stopped practicing in this area they were reached by soft interrupts.

Comment: Yes they are. So, if I consider 4GB address space then around half of the space contains kernel code/data and half user space progs. Kernel code remains same across all user space progs. When u want to invoke any kernel routine then the way to go there is software interrupts as u dont have access to that address range. What I want to know is how those kernel virtual addresses are given.

Comment: @agent.smith if you accept what I say, the question is meaningless. The kernel has its own address space which is distinct from any process's user-mode space, so the question of how kernel addresses are mapped into user space cannot possibly arise.